# Combine two string values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [11, 22, 33], 'vehicles': ['taxi', 'Taxi', 'Truck]})

df
        
        numbers      vehicles
0          11           taxi
1          22           Taxi
2          33           Truck
```

I want to conflate `taxi` and `Taxi` to be able to retrieve `Taxi`. For example:

```
df

        numbers      vehicles
0          33           Taxi
1          33           Truck
```

How can I get this done.

Comment: `df['numbers'].groupby(df['vehicles'].str.lower()).sum()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, wouldn't that transform all the string values to lower case?

Comment: Replace `lower()` with `capitalize()` if you want to capitalize the first letters.